# Lag in animated image array

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm working on a looping animation (like an animated GIF) made from an ever-changing array of images (based on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/BT2wk/9/).)  The animation advances via a changing image class.  Here's what i have currently:

```
function animateEverything() {

var imgc = 0;

var frame1 = $('.start').attr('src');
var frame2 = $('.start').prev().attr('src');
var frame3 = $('.start').prev().prev().attr('src');
var frame4 = $('.start').prev().prev().prev().attr('src');
var frame5 = $('.start').prev().prev().prev().prev().attr('src');

var images = [frame1,frame2,frame3,frame4,frame5];

$("#ball").html("<img src='" +images[0] +"'>").show()
setTimeout(setImage, 50);

function setImage() {
    var next=new Image()
    images.push(images.shift())
    next.onload=function(){
        $("#ball img").attr("src", this.src)
    }
    next.src= images[0] 
    setTimeout(setImage, 500);   
}   

// MOVE FORWARD     
setInterval(function(){
$('.start').removeClass('start').next().addClass('start');
frame1 = $('.start').attr('src');
frame2 = $('.start').prev().attr('src');
frame3 = $('.start').prev().prev().attr('src');
frame4 = $('.start').prev().prev().prev().attr('src');
frame5 = $('.start').prev().prev().prev().prev().attr('src');
images = [frame1,frame2,frame3,frame4,frame5];
},10000);
}

animateEverything();
```

Everything's working great except when the class changes there is a delay.  I've tried fiddling with the setTimeout durations but it didn't seem to help . . . Not sure what else to try.

Any ideas on how to lose the lag?

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/milpool/v7s6e4g6/)

Comment: Do you not have access to CSS3? This can easily be done using `transition` and `transition-delay`

Comment: oops sorry @showdev updated the 2nd fiddle link it should show the working code now

Comment: @RobScott i was trying to figure out how to do this with css animation but couldn't find anything . . . but maybe i am overlooking an obvious better way to do this?  would i just do something with transition-delay and display:none/block based on class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first cache the loaded and decoded images. Loading images each time require the browser to (re)fetch the raw binary compressed image file from the network, or if lucky, the cache. Then it need to decode it, decompress it and convert it into a RGBA bitmap, which from this point can be shown.

This process can take longer than the 16.7-33.4ms you need to animate (60/30fps respectively). Every time src is set a loading process is started in the background.

So a more proper way to do this is to:

- First load all images in the background. Image loading is asynchronous so you have to handle this as well using onload handler. You should make a single handler for this and when the images has loaded properly update the frame array.
- Do not use setInterval/setTimeout. These are inaccurate and very inaccurate for animations. Instead use `requestAnimationFrame` which gives perfect sync with the monitor updates.

So in essence you need:

- an array with urls to load, which are fed to:
- image loader that handles async loading
- when image has loaded update the frame array
- animate (preloaded) images in the frames array using requestAnimationFrame

Answer (score 1):

For animation in Javascript it is often easier to use a setTimout rather than setInterval. It's better to have one function that continuously calls a function that implements the animation rather than drive the animation with multiple setIntervals.

Javascript would look like this:

```
$("#ball").html("<img src='" +images[0] +"'>").show()
setInterval(setImage, 50);

function setImage() {
  var next=new Image()
  images.push(images.shift())
  next.onload=function(){
    $("#ball img").attr("src", this.src)
  }
  next.src= images[0]   
}
```

Here is a working fiddle. I wasn't able to tell if there was any conspicuous delay.

https://jsfiddle.net/4bb0wwsz/

Comment: thanks but this doesn't incorporate changing the array which is where the lag is happening . . .

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help, I ended up taking Rob Scott's advice and switched to css animation for the flashing effect, still using jquery for the image advancement.

css:

```
img {
width:0;
height:0;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
    -webkit-animation-name: flash;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:steps(1, end);
}

.first, .second, .third, .fourth, .fifth {
display:block;width:100%;height:auto;}

.first {-webkit-animation-delay:0s;}
.second {-webkit-animation-delay:0.2s;}
.third {-webkit-animation-delay:0.4s;}
.fourth{-webkit-animation-delay:0.6s;}
.fifth{-webkit-animation-delay:0.8s;}

@-webkit-keyframes flash {0% {opacity: 1;}20% {opacity: 0;}100% {opacity: 0;}}
```

js:

```
// MOVE FORWARD 
$('.fifth').prev().addClass('fourth');
$('.fourth').prev().addClass('third');
$('.third').prev().addClass('second');
$('.second').prev().addClass('first');

setInterval(function(){ 
$('.fourth, .third, .second, .first').attr('class','');
$('.fifth').removeClass('fifth').next().addClass('fifth');
$('.fifth').prev().addClass('fourth');
$('.fourth').prev().addClass('third');
$('.third').prev().addClass('second');
$('.second').prev().addClass('first');

},10000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/milpool/et05pvw5/