# Latency with animationiteration

Tags: javascript, css-animations

So I've got this modal that I've designed to be opened via a checkbox input, but the problem with that was that I have my divs and section arranged in such a manner that `#yt-modal-cont` can't be in the same container as my input due to z-index issues. So I used javascript:

```
if(modalToggle.checked === true) {
  oLay.style.display = 'block';}
```

Simple enough fix, however, that's not my issue. For the animation, the route I chose was:

```
#yt-modal-cont {
  animation: fade-before 0.3s ease-out 0s 2 alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes fade-before {
  0%{opacity:1;}
  100%{opacity:0;}
}

<script>
  var oLay = document.getElementById('yt-modal-cont');
  var modalToggle = document.getElementById('vids');

  function fadein(){
    oLay.style['animation-play-state'] = 'paused';
  }

  function isOpen(){
    if(modalToggle.checked === true) {
       oLay.style.display = 'block';}
       oLay.addEventListener('animationiteration', fadein);
    }
  }
  modalToggle.addEventListener('click', isOpen);
</script>
```

and then for the closing function I have it setting `animation-play-state=running` to play through to the end, but that's not relevant. My issue is that javascript seems to be catching the end of the first iteration--and thusly adding the style--too late, as when the modal opens it's opacity is faded slightly. What's weirder, is that it's only sometimes; I open it once and it's kinda faded, I open it again and it's full opacity, then again and it's really faded... I tried adding `oLay.style.opacity = 1` to the fadein function to try and override the CSS but it's still hit-or-miss. After looking at

[Lag in animated image array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626782/lag-in-animated-image-array)

I feel that `requestAnimationframe` might be the answer, but my js newb-iness makes it so that I don't really understand what that's all about... Is that the right track or is there a different solution?